# UIImageView, UIView, taking a segment of a picture

Tags: iphone

I want to take an image from the UIImagePickerController and put it on a UIImageView that can move based on touch.  I'm not sure how to get the picture onto the UIImageView.  I thought the UIImageView automatically resizes the picture, so I couldn't grab just the top half of the picture and put that on the UIImageView.  Is there an easy way to do this?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to crop (take a segment of?) a picture.  Put a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView to let the user scroll through (move based on touch) a large image.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move and zoom your picture in a view, you need to use a UIScrollView. See Apple's ScrollViewSuite example. If you simply want to position the picture within a UIImageView, set the contentMode of the UIImageView to the setting you want e.g. scale, top, left, etc. See the UIImageView documentation for all options.